# Avoid a revision is automatically published

Tags: nodes

I currently have new revisions created whenever a page is edited, but I don't want it to be automatically published. Instead, I want to have to go into the revision tab and click revert for the latest revision. Is this incorporated in Drupal 7 or do I have to download a module?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [Revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning) module, this is probably what you are looking for.
There is simpler module [Revision Moderation](http://drupal.org/project/revision_moderation), but it has no D7 version